Connect to a database using Prisma in a Remix app built with Vite
Before switching to Vite this was working fine:
In the .env declared DATABASE_URL variable:
DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:Password@localhost:3306/myAppDB"

and in the schema.prisma:
datasource db {
  provider = "mysql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}


But after switching to Vite I need to manually write which gives warning as it's not safe:
datasource db {
  provider = "mysql"
  url      = "mysql://root:Password@localhost:3306/myAppDB"
}


Cause fetching from the .env using env() doesn't work anymore apparently. Also saw vite recommending to use VITE_ at the start of the environment variables(here's the link). So I also tried like:
In the .env:
VITE_DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:Password@localhost:3306/myAppDB"schema.prisma

And in the schema.prisma:
datasource db {
  provider = "mysql"
  url      = env("VITE_DATABASE_URL")
}

But this failed as well.
